# Would an observer at infinity see a black hole decay before anything reaches the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, hawking-radiation

I’ve just watched a lecture on black holes by Leonard Susskind. He states that it takes an infinite amount of time to an outside observer for an object to reach the event horizon. However, a black hole decays due to Hawking radiation in a finite time.

Let's say I go into a supermassive black hole - so I don't get spaghettified by the time I reach the event horizon. As I'm falling closer and closer to the black hole would the Hawking radiation speed up faster and faster to a point where when I reach the event horizon the black hole has fully decayed since it takes an infinite time to an outside observer for me to reach it but a finite amount of time to decay.

Seems weird this would mean no matter can ever reach past the event horizon as it would've already decayed by the time you get there?

Comment: Variants of this are asked very frequently. Other possible duplicates: [Would a black hole evaporate before reaching the event horizon?](/q/274333), [The nature of event horizons](/q/545476), [Falling into an evaporating black hole](/q/627370), [Can singularities be ever formed from an outsiders perspective?](/q/632600)

Comment: Did Susskind's lecture mention the **black hole complementarity** conjecture, which is concisely reviewed in the first paragraph of [arXiv:hep-th/9506138](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9506138)? That conjecture is directly relevant to your question. It was motivated by a similar line of questions collectively called the **black hole information paradox**. The complementarity conjecture was challenged several years ago by the **firewall paradox**, but that seems to be resolved now. The review [arXiv:1609.00026](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00026) helps put these things in context.